# "Free space" volume in the nucleus

Tags: literature, eukaryotic-cells, systems-biology

Take a mammalian cell, say a HeLa cell for concreteness. If a molecule (e.g. a transcription factor) enters the nucleus, what is the effective volume that it can explore/access there by free diffusion? That is, the total volume of the nucleus minus the chromatin, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a clear (or answerable) question without more detail — it also would be improved by you telling us: where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. ——— One example of a problem with the way you've worded your questions is that chromatin isn't an impenetrable solid, which is why molecules including proteins like transcription factors can directly bind to DNA! ——— It also likely to help if you provided some background about why you care about this number.

Comment: No, the question is clear and perfectly answerable: what is the subvolume of the nucleus that a molecule can access by free diffusion? A ref for the total nuclear volume is easy to find (e.g. [bionumbers](https://bionumbers.hms.harvard.edu/bionumber.aspx?id=106665&ver=7&trm=nuclear+free+volume)). In Alberts et al., Essential cell biology (5th ed.), question/answer 5-2 estimates that 18% of the nuclear volume are occupied by DNA + histones. That's all so far. Any type of cell would do as a guideline.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the relevant information from your comment and add complete reference information. Comments are ephemeral and often overlooked and so should only be used to discuss improvements for posts. ——— Some examples of why this question isn't clear: 1) chromatin is **not** a solid — and the porosity is dynamic; 2) volume will fluctuate depending on what the cell is doing (for instance with cell-cycle state); and 3) even within a single cell the "free volume" is going to vary depending on the molecule that is diffusing.